# Only call function if PyMOL running

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pymol

I have a script that performs some calculations on a protein. When it's finished, a method imports the `pymol` module, and uses the `pymol.cmd` API to display results in a PyMOL session. The process is something akin to the following:

```
def display_results(results, protein_fn):
    import pymol
    pymol.cmd.load(protein_fn)
    pymol.cmd.alter(...)
    ...

protein_fn = "1abc.ent"
results = analyze_protein(protein_fn)
display_results(results, protein_fn)
```

However, my script doesn't necessarily *need* to display the results in PyMOL, and I'd like this to only be done if PyMOL is installed and running.

It's easy to check if PyMOL is installed (I can just `try: import pymol`), but is there a way to check if there's an active PyMOL session to display results in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on PyMOL (haven't ever scripted it) but I see 2 possible ways:

1. Do something trivial that requires an open PyMOL session and catch
   exceptions
2. Look at process names (something like `os.system("ps ux |
   grep -i pymol")`)

First way is better, second is a dirty hack.

Comment: Method 1 is straightforward enough, and aligns well with Pyhon's "EAFP" policy. It's probably what I'll go with if there's no clear API solution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do something like:

```
try:
    import pymol
    pymol_imported = True
except:
    pymol_imported = False
```

Then

```
if pymol_imported:
    display_results(...)
```

I don't know if that's Python "best practices", but PyMol scripts are usually just quick, one-off things in most cases, anyways.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, but as I noted in the question, checking if PyMOL is installed is trivial. My problem was whether to check if PyMOL is _running_.