# Call current PyMOL session from python script

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, pymol

I'm trying to call current PyMOL session from python script (wxpython GUI), and then load some data from PyMOL and send few commands to PyMOL. At the moment I can open a new PyMOL session in python script:

```
import sys, os
from wx import *
app = wx.App()
dialog = wx.FileDialog ( None, message = 'Set PyMOL directiry', style = wx.OPEN)
if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    # Pymol path
    moddir = dialog.GetDirectory()
    sys.path.insert(0, moddir)
    os.environ['PYMOL_PATH'] = moddir

    import pymol
    pymol.finish_launching()     
else:
    print 'Nothing was selected.'

from pymol import *   
dialog1 = wx.FileDialog ( None, message = 'Set PDB file', style = wx.OPEN)
if dialog1.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    pdbfile = dialog1.GetPath()
    cmd.load(pdbfile)
else:
    print 'Nothing was selected.'

dialog.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```

BUT actually I'd like to check in my python scrip whether any PyMOL session is already opened. 
I found discussion corresponding to this topic here:
[Only call function if PyMOL running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858681/only-call-function-if-pymol-running)
Following this discussion I tried to call 'print' function in PyMOL:

```
try:
    from pymol import cmd
    print 'Connected'
except:
    <open new Pymol sesssion>
```

but I do not see any text in PyMOL cmd. I tried to determine PyMOL path before this statement and again I failed.

Does anyone know how to call current PyMOL session from python script?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to interact with an existing PyMOL session from the Python interpreter. There are a few alternatives:

1. The existing PyMOL command prompt accepts valid Python and you can [run any script](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Running_Scripts) directly from the prompt. Perhaps you could execute your script from there instead?
2. You can start up a new PyMOL session as part of your script. PyMOL's `-i` flag may be especially helpful- it enables you to work in a headless environment:

   ```
   -i     Disable the internal OpenGL GUI (object list, menus, etc.)
   ```
3. Take a careful look at PyMOL's `__init.py__`. You'll find the intricacies of PyMOL's threading there. Perhaps you can find something useful to manipulate?

#### Side note:

Calling `print` from your script will *not* make the text appear in the PyMOL session, it will merely write the text to standard output (i.e. it will be printed to your terminal).

---

The following PyMOL wiki pages may be of help to you:

- [Running scripts](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Running_Scripts)
- [Launching PyMOL](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Category%3aLaunching)
- [Launching from a script](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Launching_From_a_Script)